# Firebase gives error on database listener when signing out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I managed to make an authentication functionality, where the user can use:

1. sign up
2. log in
3. update / delete account
4. sign out

Everything works good until I sign out. I use `onSnapshot()` for the update functionality
So everytime the auth state changes i set the returned data in the component's state.

```
firebase_auth.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

    if(user) {

     firebase.collection('users').doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(doc => {

      doc.exists && this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, user_data: doc.data() }));      

     });

 } else this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, user_data: null }));

});

signOut() {

 firebase.auth().signOut();

}
```

When i sign out the following error occurs:

> Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Here are my database rules. I use [firebase cloud storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).

```
service cloud.firestore {    
  match /databases/{database}/documents {      
    match /users/{uid} {        
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid      
    }    
  }  
}
```

And if i stop the `onSnapshot listener`, not even the `log in` will work.

```
firebase_auth.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

    if(user) {

     const unsubscribe = firebase.collection('users').doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(doc => {

       doc.exists && this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, user_data: doc.data() }));
     });

     unsubscribe();

 } else this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, user_data: null }));

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix for this problem is:

```
firebase_auth.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

  if(user) {

   const unsubscribe = firebase.collection('users').doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(doc => {

    doc.exists && this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, user_data: doc.data() }));   

   });

   this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, unsubscribe });

 } else this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, user_data: null }));

});
```

I set the `unsubscribe` function in the `state`, and use it later in the `sign out`:

```
signOut() {
  this.state.unsubscribe();
  firebase.auth().signOut();
}
```

Thank you [frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen).

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Firestore security rules requite that the user is authenticated to read certain data. For that reason, the listener(s) for that data get rejected when you sign the user out.

The solution to prevent the error message, is to remove the listeners yourself in your code before signing the user out. So keep the `unsubscribe` in a field in the object where you can reach it from `signOut()`, and then:

```
signOut() {
  unsubscribe();
  firebase.auth().signOut();
}
```

Comment: I post the answer kudos to you my friend.